# Import SCSS swiper into svelte component error

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, swiper.js

I'm trying to use swiper in svelte. so, I follow the documentation here
https://swiperjs.com/svelte

When I add  `import 'swiper/swiper.scss';` to my component. I get an error says:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

Anyone can help me out, please?

Comment: try this `import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';`

Comment: Happy you got a solution, but it should be possible to include an `scss` file in your svelte components. We might need to see more of the component and your rollup.

Comment: Yes, That's right. I hope there is an answer for that too. @ConnorLow

Comment: @Hussein, please add your rollup/webpack configuration, and any svelte preprocessor configurations.